# DataReader.Read running very slow

Tags: c#, sql, datareader, sqlperformance

As the title of question, I got issue relate to read data from MS-SQL.
I wrote a C# code using DataReader for retrieving data return from query and save data to CVS. It very simple and I pretty sure there is no problem with this code.

I have two queries. The first query is result from inner join 4 tables.
The second query using Row_Num and subqueries in the select statement. All of them return 24 columns.
The first query return 321k records. The second query return 2300 records.
I am using SQL server 2008.

Problem is when I run with first query, it work fast. 321k records save to CVS file and take 8 mins to complete. But with the second query, it take 26 hours to save 2300 records to file. I put the log in code and I found some record take 40 - 50 mins to read data and I don't know why.

Please take a look and give me some suggestion.

bellow is my code and what I did

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(secondQuery, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        using (var memoryStream = ExtendedStream.CreateMemoryStream())
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, 65536))    {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // using Nlog to log start time begin read data and log what happen on code
                // read property value and save to file
                // using Nlog to log end time read data
            }
        }
        reader.Dispose();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Second query

```sql
WITH TEMP AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SId,PointID ORDER BY UTCSysTime) Record_No, * FROM
    (SELECT
        *
        FROM
        Table_A WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE
        StatusID IN (1, 2)
        AND [UTCSysTime] >= @StartTime
        AND [UTCSysTime] <= @EndTime
        UNION
        SELECT
        E.*
        FROM
        Table_A E WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        SId,
                        PointID,
                        StatusID,
                        UTCSysTime = MIN(UTCSysTime)
                    FROM
                        Table_A WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE
                        StatusID IN (1, 2)
                        AND [UTCSysTime] > @EndTime
                    GROUP BY
                        SId,
                        PointID,
                        StatusID
                    ) E2
            ON E.SId = E2.SId
                AND E.PointID = E2.PointID
                AND E.StatusID = E2.StatusID
                AND E.UTCSysTime = E2.UTCSysTime
    ) T
)

SELECT
    *,
    [PointShortName] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (SELECT TOP 1
                                            ShortName
                                          FROM
                                            Table_B _T
                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                          WHERE
                                            _T.PointID = Table_T.PointID
                                         )),
    [Description_Point] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), (SELECT TOP 1
                                            _T.Name
                                           FROM
                                            Table_Point _T
                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                           WHERE
                                            _T.PointID = Table_T.PointID
                                            AND _T.DescID = 1
                                          )),
    [Description_1] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (SELECT TOP 1
                                                            Name
                                                         FROM
                                                            Table_C
                                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                         WHERE
                                                            DescID = 1
                                                            AND CatID = [Table_T].[Cat1]
                                                        )),
    [Description_2] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (SELECT TOP 1
                                                            Name
                                                         FROM
                                                            Table_C
                                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                         WHERE
                                                            DescID = 1
                                                            AND CatID = [Table_T].[Cat2]
                                                        )),
    [Description_3] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (SELECT TOP 1
                                                            Name
                                                         FROM
                                                            Table_C
                                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                         WHERE
                                                            DescID = 1
                                                            AND CatID = [Table_T].[Cat3]
                                                        )),
    [Description_4] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (SELECT TOP 1
                                                            Name
                                                         FROM
                                                            Table_C
                                                            WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                         WHERE
                                                            DescID = 1
                                                            AND CatID = [Table_T].[Cat4]
                                                        ))
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
     FROM
        (SELECT 
            a.*
            ,UTCSysTime_End = ISNULL(CASE WHEN b.StatusID = 1
                                                 THEN b.UTCSysTime
                                            END,
                                            CASE WHEN c.StatusID = 1
                                                 THEN c.UTCSysTime
                                            END)

  FROM TEMP a LEFT OUTER JOIN  TEMP b ON a.Record_no = b.Record_no - 1 and a.SId = b.SId and a.PointID = b.PointID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  TEMP c ON a.Record_no = c.Record_no - 2 and a.SId = c.SId and a.PointID = c.PointID) E
     WHERE
        E.StatusID = 2
        AND [UTCSysTime] >= @StartTime
        AND [UTCSysTime] <= @EndTime
    ) [Table_T]
WHERE
    [UTCSysTime] > @StartTime
    AND [UTCSysTime] <= @EndTime
```

I tried to run query on SSMS and both of them work well. I tried to use SQL Profiler but my account have no permission. So i put the log into source code. And I saw some records take 50-60 mins to read and write to file.

The log is:

> 2019-09-09 07:48:40.5242 | DEBUG | End writing row number 226 | Exception:
>   2019-09-09 07:48:40.5522 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 227 | Exception:
>  
>   2019-09-09 07:48:40.5802 | DEBUG | End writing row number 227 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 07:48:40.6072 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 228 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 07:48:40.6352 | DEBUG | End writing row number 228 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 07:48:40.6632 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 229 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 08:20:50.3977 | DEBUG | End writing row number 229 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 08:20:50.4337 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 230 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 08:20:50.4667 | DEBUG | End writing row number 230 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 08:20:50.5047 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 231 | Exception: 
>   2019-09-09 08:20:50.5387 | DEBUG | End writing row number 231 | Exception:

Comment: With no clue about your select statements, I can only suggest checking SQL Profiler and SSMS execution plan

Comment: You have subselects and row_num? Looks like that query could use some indexing/statistics (for the row_num) and the subqueries should be eliminated.

Comment: "...and Select in select method" Internally the SQL Server in your second query is doing: 1 select for the main block of data, a table scan for the row_num, and **2300** extra select statements for the subqueries ("select in select"). If you need help with your second SQL statement, edit your question and add it. Check [mcve]

Comment: Try to use `reader.GetOrdinal("CloumnName")` against `reader[i]` it could have huge performance impact.

Comment: `it take 26 hours to save 2300 records to files` How large is the resulting file?

Comment: @mjwills ~2mb with second query. and ~60mb with first query

Comment: `I cannot run SQLProfiler because my account have no permission.` Can you clone the database to a local instance of SQL Server and then run the code against that database (so you can profile locally)?

Comment: @mjwills there are a lot of data on that so I cannot clone the database to local. Beside of that. I got approve to public query but need to modify column name, table name, db name. Could you take a look on that.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] of the C# you are using to execute the SQL. As well as a [mcve] of the exact SQL you are executing in SSMS (which is running faster).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do here is to identify whether the problem is input vs output; to do that, I would simply comment out all the output code, so you have (just showing the uncommented code):

```cs
while (reader.Read())
{
    count++;
} 
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

If that is still slow, then the problem is at the database. We can't see your query, tables, indices or data - so we can't help you tune it, but: that's where you'd need to look.

If it is fast without the output code, the problem is in your writing code. You show `ExtendedStream.CreateMemoryStream`; this doesn't appear to be part of the regular framework, so I can't comment on how this is expected to perform, but if you're writing a file, frankly I'd try *just using the inbuilt framework types for that* - `FileStream` etc.

I'd also minimize the amount of `Console` output, perhaps only showing updates every N rows for some N. You aren't trying to profile the console.

Comment: With that delay I would bet on database. But sadly there is no info whatsoever on the SQL queries executed.

Comment: @bradbury9 indeed; I doubled down on that point: "We can't see your query, tables, indices or data - so we can't help you tune it, but: that's where you'd need to look."

Comment: If issue come from code block in while {}, it should be slow too with the first query, right ?

Comment: @CaPhamVan that is complex: "it depends". It is the difference between TTFB and TTLB. If your query takes a long time to *start*, then yes it could be slow *before* it even gets to the loop.

Comment: If the query has subqueries in the select statement, looping through it could take long. That is a O(n) problem.

Comment: I tried to run the second query on SSMS and it take 3 -4 mins to complete. I cannot run SQL Profiler because I have no permission.
The issue only happen with some records. 
Bellow is my log file: 
`
2019-09-08 07:48:40.6352 | DEBUG | End writing row number 228 | Exception: 
2019-09-08 07:48:40.6632 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 229 | Exception: 
2019-09-08 08 :20:50.3977 | DEBUG | End writing row number 229 | Exception: 
2019-09-08 08:20:50.4337 | DEBUG | Start writing row number 230 | Exception: 
2019-09-08 08:20:50.4667 | DEBUG | End writing row number 230 | 
`

Comment: @CaPhamVan and does the data contain a lot of large CLOB/BLOB columns? (`varbinary(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` etc) - SSMS may be avoiding fetching the full contents of CLOB/BLOB data, where-as you'll be fetching the entire column contents here

Comment: @MarcGravell there is no big columns in the table. all of them are number, short text and date time.

Comment: An amateur comments: perhaps look at the Index->Properties->Options for the table and set 'Allow Row Locks'=false and 'Allow Page Locks'=false.  Seemed to do the trick for me ..